# SQL - NEWID() producing the same guid on an update query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, newid

In a table I have created a new column that's going to hold a randomized alphanumeric string. I've been using the NEWID() function. From my understanding, NEWID should just create a new guid per row but all my rows end up with the same guid.

My code is:

```
DECLARE @random_guid
SET @random_guid = NEWID()
UPDATE this_table
SET random_column = @random_guid
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You need a 'where' clause to restrict which rows to update. Currently it updates every row in the table.

Comment: You are setting a _variable_ to a single value and then using that _variable_ for every row.  If you called the function directly it _would_ call it for every row.

Comment: Currently I am using a 'where' clause to test on a handful of rows so I don't change everything but it will eventually need to change every row

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's probably cause you are setting the variable first and using it. Rather directly use the function like

```
UPDATE this_table
SET random_column = NEWID();
```

Comment: That worked so thank you for that. But a different issue arose. I was using this as a salt for password hashing (I know guids are bad but it's the easiest way I have to suddenly give a lot of records hashed passwords). If I set my update statement like the above code, can I access what the value of random_column is set to?

Comment: @RobynDias, Yes you can ... probably you might want to post a separate question with your new issue.